# Redux Native How to navigate with react-navigation-redux-helpers

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation, action

I would like to know how can I fire navigation actions in React Native (with the react-navigation-redux-helpers) ?

I tired to use NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'App' }) function but nope :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-navigation` gives you action creators, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',

  params: {},

  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SubProfileRoute' }),
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')
```

Comment: That would be fine, but I want to use the redux helper to fire the navigation.

Comment: nvm solved, I had to dispatch the function itself. Thanks anyway m8! :)